# The syntax of Symbol.iterator is difficult

Tags: typescript

Good morning. I would like to inquire about Symbol.iterator.

```
interface IterableIterator<T> extends Iterator<T>{
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;
};
```

Many examples use the same syntax as above.

But I know that [] is an array, and () is a function operator.

```
[Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;
```

I know that IterableIterator < T > is a type.

And in front of that is the name of the variable.

```
[Symbol.iterator]()
```

Is this syntax specific to implementing prototype's Symbol.iterator?

Comment: `[]` is **not** always an array; in this case it's a [*computed property name*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). No, this syntax isn't specific to the iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question, I will need to explain a few additions to ECMAScript (since TypeScript is a superset of ECMAScript) in ES6.

### Computed property names

When you define an object literal in ES5 (plain old JavaScript), you can only use fixed property names:

```
var key = 'superKey';

var a = {
    key: 1
}
```

`key` above is used literally and the value of variable `key` is ignored, so that object literal will be equivalent to

```
var a = {
    'key': 1
}
```

If you wanted to use the string in `key` variable dynamically as an object property name, you would have to write:

```
var key = 'superKey';
var a = {};
a[key] = 1;
```

ES6 brings a solution to this problem: you can now use an arbitrary expression as a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) when defining an object literal:

```
let key = 'superKey';
let a = {
    [key]: 1,
    [key + key]: 2
}
```

The same is also applicable to ES6 classes and TypeScript classes and interfaces:

```
const s = 'foo';

interface IFoo {
    [s](): number;
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    [s]() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

### Symbols

Symbols are a new primitive type introduced in ES6, which can be used to index objects along with strings:

```
let s = Symbol();
let a = {
    [s]: 1
}
a[s] === 1
```

There are a few *well-known symbols*, which are used to look up methods for some special cases.  These symbols are defined as properties on the global Symbol function.

One of these well-known symbols is `Symbol.iterator`: when you write `for item of someObject`, internally `someObject[Symbol.iterator]` is called.

### Summing up

```
interface IterableIterator<T> extends Iterator<T>{
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;
};
```

This defines an interface with a method which is accessible as `obj[Symbol.iterator]` and returns an object of type `IterableIterator<T>`.

Comment: Thank you. 
In summary, that is a function that returns an IterableIterator <T>, and the reason [] is because of the computed property name. I understood.

Answer (score 0):

Those `[]` that you are seeing where `[Symbol.iterator]` is placed inside of is new for ES6 and its called key interpolation. So if you want a dynamically generated key you can wrap it in square braces. So its a completely normal key.

My understanding and experience with `[Symbol.iterator]` is that its a tool that teaches objects how to respond to the for of loop.